# Implicit parameter in singleton class

Tags: coq

When I create a typeclass with a single method in the usual syntax, I can give it implicit parameters:

```
Class Foo1 := { foo1 {n} : Int n }.
```

But when I use the singleton syntax, I can't give it the implicit parameter

```
Fail Class Foo2 := foo2 {n} : Int n.
```

> Error: Syntax error: '.' expected after [gallina] (in [vernac_aux]).

I can't even use `Arguments` to make that parameter implicit:

```
Class Foo3 := foo3 n : Int n.
Fail Arguments foo3 {n}.
```

> The command has indeed failed with message: Flag "rename" expected to rename Foo3 into n.

Is there a reason for it to work this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### On your 2nd attempt

Your second try could work by moving the `n` on the other side of the colon:

```
Class Foo2 := foo2 : forall {n}, Int n.
```

### On your 3rd attempt

The error message tells you to use the `rename` flag. This is because `foo3` in fact takes `Foo3` (the typeclass instance it projects from) as a first (implicit) argument, before the integer. This first argument happens to already have a name (`Foo3`), as you can see by running `About foo3.`

```
About foo3.
(*
foo3 : Foo3 -> forall n : nat, Int n

Arguments foo3 {Foo3} _%nat_scope
*)
```

Hence Coq believes you want to rename *that* argument to `n`. If that was really what you wanted, you could do it using the `rename` flag as suggested:

```
Arguments foo3 {n} : rename.
```

After which `About foo3.` will yield:

```
foo3 : Foo3 -> forall n0 : nat, Int n0

Arguments foo3 {n} n%nat_scope
  (where some original arguments have been renamed)
```

But what you actually want is to affect the *second* argument by making it implicit. In the process, you don’t want to give it a new name (no need, it is already named `n`), and you don’t want to alter the first argument (i.e. you keep it implicit and avoid renaming it). Hence, what you should do is:

```
Arguments foo3 {_ _}.
```

Yielding

```
Arguments foo3 {Foo3} {n}%nat_scope
```

Comment: Is there a reason why the two variants work so differently for the implicit argument?

Comment: I updated my answer to provide a way to circumvent your issue.

Comment: Thanks @Maëlan, I went too fast indeed. I updated the answer accordingly if that is alright with you.

Comment: Thanks! I took the liberty of editing your answer further. :-)